# Magento Any mail is not sending

Tags: magento-1.9, email, cron

I have used Magento 1.9.2.2. Any Magento mail is not sending. I already set a cron on the server-side but my issue still exists. please give proper solution.

Comment: Install aoe_scheduler plugin and get it confirmed that cron works fine.

Comment: is mail server is installed in server? can you try with smtp extension.